# Day_Only in SOQL considering timezone

Tags: soql, timezone

I am writing a SOQL query in Apex like:

```
Select Id From Case Where Day_Only(Date_Time_Order_Received__c) >= :startDate
```

But it seems to me that the Day_Only function will calculate the datetime field based on GMT time. Is there a way to use log in user's time instead of GMT time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SOQL has a function called `convertTimezone()` that you can use in other date functions to return the value converted to the user's timezone:

```
Select Id From Case 
Where Day_Only(convertTimezone(Date_Time_Order_Received__c)) >= :startDate
```

[Converting Time Zones in Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm)

**For Info**:

> SOQL queries in a client application return dateTime field values as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) values. You can use convertTimezone() in a date function to convert dateTime fields to the user’s time zone.

Comment: I there a page in the SFDC docs where we can find all the functions available in SOQL ?,  cause I am discovering the existence of new function supported in SOQL every week :p

Comment: The [Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm) is the primary reference. Definitely worth reading.

Comment: @benahm Salesforce is very well documented and the *developer guides* are quite good for `SOQL and SOSL`, `SOAP API`, `Metadata API`, `Tooling API`, and so on.

Comment: @AdrianLarson In the case of APIs it's OK but in case of SOQL I dont find that well documented, example I've tried a group by in a where subquery got error parse, but when I check the doc => https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm nothing tells me that is not supported in that case ....